# Can I use the try-catch with the callback route instead when I am using the promises or async/await in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, callback, try-catch

I am using `nested callbacks` in my app code.
Do I need to or Can I use the `try/catch` after route since I just thought that callback functions have already first argument as `error` so whenever error comes it will fetch inside `error block if condition.` But on `Heroku` when I am testing my code somewhere it crashed means its still unable to handle the errors properly means the error is not getting called inside `if(error)` block.

So I thought I must use one `try-catch` as well before writing my code.

Below is the code with `try-catch` and nested callback functions.

Let me know if its correct please:

```
 router.route('/addTasks-writers').get(function (req, res) {
    try {
        User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.query.val }, { $push: { Addtasks: element } }, function (error, data) {
            if (data) {
                console.log("data pushed to the Addtasks in Writer");
    
                User.updateMany({ "Addtasks._id": req.query.id },
                    {
                        $set: {
                            "Addtasks.$.assignee": req.query.assignee,
                            "Addtasks.$.deadline": req.query.deadline,
                            "Addtasks.$.status": 'Requirement Submitted',
                            "Addtasks.$.background": 'linear-gradient(223.88deg, #FF149D 8.89%, #620F32 94.31%)'
                        }
                    },
                    function (error, success) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log("error");
                            res.end('{"msg" : "Unable to set the Writer and deadline for the Task", "status" : 700}');
                        } else {
                            console.log("req.query.assignee = " + req.query.assignee);
                            console.log("req.query.assignee = " + req.query.deadline);
                            console.log("updated the assignee in admin dashboard");
                            res.end('{"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200}');
                        }
                    })
            }
}
catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
      }
        })
```

Comment: You cannot use `try/catch` as a substitute for checking every single `err` parameter in callbacks - it will not catch those errors.  `try/catch` works flawlessly to catch awaited promises that reject upon error when using only promise-based APIs (no plain callbacks).  This is one of the huge advantages of using promise-based APIs or promisifying the non-promise APIs you have.

Comment: @jfriend00 Then why in my heroku I suddenly gets the application error since i am using the error block with callback functions?

Comment: You'd have to show the exact error message and the exact line of code that had the error for me to have any possibility to help with a specific error.  If heroku is saying you had an application error, then perhaps that is because you did not properly catch the error.

Comment: But with callbacks wwe cannot use catch block. Its by default is having the error argument inside the function rememeber?

Comment: I don't understand what that last comment means.  Please refer to a specific piece of code rather than general questions that don't show specific code.